# Flask web-development linking to an image

Tags: html, image, flask

So, I have this source HTML, and

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="abstract">
   <div>
    <img src="../images/rprog.png" width="200" height="200">
    <h2 class="articletitle">R Programming</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="abstract">
    <h2>Article 2<h2>
    <h3>Data Mining Researcher, Machine Learning, Statistical Pattern Recognition<h3>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

My app directory structure is given below:

```
app/
├── articles
│   └── R_Programming.html
├── images
│   └── rprog.png
├── routes.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── main.css
│   └── js
│       └── googleanalytics.js
└── templates
    ├── about.html
    ├── home.html
    └── layout.html
```

but the image is not displayed:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is *static content*. Put all images in the `static` folder and use the `static` route to load them.

You can use `url_for()` in your template to produce a valid URL for them:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/rprog.png') }}" width="200" height="200">
```

This will generate a URL to load the `static/images/rprog.png` file.